# How can I fully use the chroot I create with debootstrap on a local machine?

Tags: networking, debootstrap, container

I'm running on a Ubuntu 10.04, and installed an 8.04 version in a directory `/stuff/hardy`

`sudo debootstrap --variant buildd --arch i386 hardy /stuff/hardy http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

What I want to do is to get a working environment isolated from my linux machine (without installing into another partition).

My problem is, that when I chroot into it (`sudo chroot /stuff/hardy`) I notice that I have nothing in `/proc` or no network configuration. Also, if I try to go back to my home directory (inside hardy, not 10.4),

`hardy# cd`
 I get a 
`/home/myuser No such file or directory`

Is there an (hopefully easy) way to get an ubuntu install using `debootstrap` with no a lot of extra work ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use QEMU emulation as explained at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281763/is-there-any-prebuilt-qemu-ubuntu-image32bit-online/1081171#1081171

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use schroot instead of chroot, it will take care of setting up /proc, /etc and cross mount your home.
You can use the following script which helps to build/setup a schroot:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~debfactory-devs/debfactory/devel/download/head%3A/schroot_build.py-20090314124651-txt9bwioeycax53m-1/build_schroot.py

Comment: I ran the script, but problems remain. Still receive the "is /proc mounted? " message, and /proc is empty.

Comment: Did you switch to the chroot using the "schroot" command ? Please note that "s" .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `schroot` is the way to go if you want to set up a more complete environment in your chroot. I recommend installing *ubuntu-dev-tools* and using `mk-sbuild` which will do everything for you automatically.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/mk-sbuild.1.html