# Is there any prebuilt QEMU Ubuntu image(32bit) online?

Tags: qemu

I am playing with QEMU. Here I found some prebuilt OS images:

http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/admin/content/starting-images.html

But they are all meant for a 64-bit system while my system is 32 bit. Does anyone know if there is any 32-bit prebuilt image online?

So I can directly use them and not need to bother with the installation.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you shore you can only have a 32-bit operating system? It's only depending on the CPU.

Comment: @Alvar  I am not quite sure. My host is Fedora 12 with kernel 2.6.29. I believe my OS is 32 bit. Processor is Intel Core 2 Duo CPU E8400. I just use the command "qemu-kvm -m 1024 img". Img is downloaded from the website I gave. It just stopped at "loading initial ramdisk"....

Comment: Yes your CPU has 64-bit compatibility. [Source](http://ark.intel.com/products/33910)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick Google search revealed the following *(I have not tried any of them)*:

- [stacklet.com](http://stacklet.com/downloads/images/lister/Ubuntu/12.04/x86)
- [Ubuntu Cloud Images](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/)

Also, you can use [vmbuilder](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests)(referred here as `ubuntu-vmbuilder`) to quickly create Ubuntu images to KVM, VirtualBox, etc.

As a last resort, you can use `qemu-img` command to convert disk images from VirtualBox/VMware to a format more suited to QEMU/KVM (this may not be needed: I think QEMU/KVM can work with other image types like vdi or vmdk).

```
$ qemu-img convert -f [vdi|vmdk|...] -O qcow2 OriginalImage NewImage
```

**NOTE**: If you are using a 32bit OS you cannot run 64bit virtual machines with KVM. But QEMU is an emulator, so it should let you run 64bit vm's on a 32bit operating system. But the performance overhead will probably be huge!

Answer (score 30):

This answer contains detailed steps for the following setups:

- cloud image amd64 and arm64
- debootstrap amd64 and arm64
- desktop image amd64

All was tested on an Ubuntu 18.04 host targeting 18.04 guests.

### Cloud image amd64

The Ubuntu cloud images are pre-installed images that allow your to boot directly without doing the usual desktop system installation. See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/438611/what-are-ubuntu-cloud-images

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo apt-get install cloud-image-utils qemu

# This is already in qcow2 format.
img=ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img
if [ ! -f "$img" ]; then
  wget "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/${img}"

  # sparse resize: does not use any extra space, just allows the resize to happen later on.
  # https://superuser.com/questions/1022019/how-to-increase-size-of-an-ubuntu-cloud-image
  qemu-img resize "$img" +128G
fi

user_data=user-data.img
if [ ! -f "$user_data" ]; then
  # For the password.
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137679/login-credentials-of-ubuntu-cloud-server-image/53373376#53373376
  # https://serverfault.com/questions/920117/how-do-i-set-a-password-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-image/940686#940686
  # https://askubuntu.com/questions/507345/how-to-set-a-password-for-ubuntu-cloud-images-ie-not-use-ssh/1094189#1094189
  cat >user-data <<EOF
#cloud-config
password: asdfqwer
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
EOF
  cloud-localds "$user_data" user-data
fi

qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -drive "file=${img},format=qcow2" \
  -drive "file=${user_data},format=raw" \
  -device rtl8139,netdev=net0 \
  -enable-kvm \
  -m 2G \
  -netdev user,id=net0 \
  -serial mon:stdio \
  -smp 2 \
  -vga virtio \
;
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/blob/603cfbb1eafe872009522a7d43a7636b71ab3b70/ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.sh).

After QEMU starts, you might have to hit enter for the boot menu to show. Select `Ubuntu` from there.

Then, the beginning of boot says:

```
error: no such device: root.

Press any key to continue...
```

but even if you don't press any key, boot continues after a short timeout. Go upvote this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1726476

Once boot finishes, login with:

- username: `ubuntu`
- password: `asdfqwer`

Internet works normally.

### Cloud image arm64

TODO: I noticed that there is a bug that happens sometimes when using this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1818197

Very similar to amd64, but we need some UEFI black magic for it to boot.

```
sudo apt-get install cloud-image-utils qemu-system-arm qemu-efi

# Get the image.
img=ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-arm64.img
if [ ! -f "$img" ]; then
  wget "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/${img}"
  qemu-img resize "$img" +128G
fi

# For the password.
user_data=user-data.img
if [ ! -f "$user_data" ]; then
  cat >user-data <<EOF
#cloud-config
password: asdfqwer
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
EOF
  cloud-localds "$user_data" user-data

  # Use the EFI magic. Picked up from:
  # https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM64/QEMU
  dd if=/dev/zero of=flash0.img bs=1M count=64
  dd if=/usr/share/qemu-efi/QEMU_EFI.fd of=flash0.img conv=notrunc
  dd if=/dev/zero of=flash1.img bs=1M count=64
fi

qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -M virt \
  -cpu cortex-a57 \
  -device rtl8139,netdev=net0 \
  -m 4096 \
  -netdev user,id=net0 \
  -nographic \
  -smp 4 \
  -drive "if=none,file=${img},id=hd0" \
  -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 \
  -drive "file=${user_data},format=raw" \
  -pflash flash0.img \
  -pflash flash1.img \
;
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/blob/0e4b5c5d6cdb0446db57ea37bc20702324a0733b/ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-arm64.sh).

### `debootstrap` amd64

Not a pre-made image, but it downloads all pre-built packages, so it is also fast, but also much more configurable and useful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eux

debootstrap_dir=debootstrap
root_filesystem=debootstrap.ext2.qcow2

sudo apt-get install \
  debootstrap \
  libguestfs-tools \
  qemu-system-x86 \
;

if [ ! -d "$debootstrap_dir" ]; then
  # Create debootstrap directory.
  # - linux-image-generic: downloads the kernel image we will use under /boot
  # - network-manager: automatically starts the network at boot for us
  sudo debootstrap \
    --include linux-image-generic \
    bionic \
    "$debootstrap_dir" \
    http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu \
  ;
  sudo rm -f "$root_filesystem"
fi

linux_image="$(printf "${debootstrap_dir}/boot/vmlinuz-"*)"

if [ ! -f "$root_filesystem" ]; then
  # Set root password.
  echo 'root:root' | sudo chroot "$debootstrap_dir" chpasswd

  # Remount root filesystem as rw.
  cat << EOF | sudo tee "${debootstrap_dir}/etc/fstab"
/dev/sda / ext4 errors=remount-ro,acl 0 1
EOF

  # Automaticaly start networking.
  # Otherwise network commands fail with:
  #     Temporary failure in name resolution
  # https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045278/ubuntu-server-18-04-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution/1080902#1080902
  cat << EOF | sudo tee "$debootstrap_dir/etc/systemd/system/dhclient.service"
[Unit]
Description=DHCP Client
Documentation=man:dhclient(8)
Wants=network.target
Before=network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/dhclient.pid
ExecStart=/sbin/dhclient -4 -q
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
  sudo ln -sf "$debootstrap_dir/etc/systemd/system/dhclient.service" \
    "${debootstrap_dir}/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhclient.service"

  # Why Ubuntu, why.
  # https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/759725
  sudo chmod +r "${linux_image}"

  # Generate image file from debootstrap directory.
  # Leave 1Gb extra empty space in the image.
  sudo virt-make-fs \
    --format qcow2 \
    --size +1G \
    --type ext2 \
    "$debootstrap_dir" \
    "$root_filesystem" \
  ;
  sudo chmod 666 "$root_filesystem"
fi

qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -append 'console=ttyS0 root=/dev/sda' \
  -drive "file=${root_filesystem},format=qcow2" \
  -enable-kvm \
  -serial mon:stdio \
  -m 2G \
  -kernel "${linux_image}" \
  -device rtl8139,netdev=net0 \
  -netdev user,id=net0 \
;
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/blob/0321da6ed378da0c850d4a448942d7ff3ffdf0e2/debootstrap-ubuntu-qemu.sh).

This boots without any systemd errors or warnings.

Now from the terminal, login with `root` / `root`, and then check that the Internet works with the following commands:

```
printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n' | nc example.com 80
apt-get update
apt-get install hello
hello
```

We used `nc` as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341518/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-manually-with-netcat/52662497#52662497 because:

- `wget` and `curl` are not installed by default
- `ping` does not work from QEMU by default: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473448/how-to-ping-from-the-qemu-guest-to-an-external-url

Analogous Debian version: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275429/creating-bootable-debian-image-with-debootstrap/473256#473256

### Build your own kernel

Since we are here:

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git
cd ubuntu-bionic
# Tag matches the working kernel that debootstrap downloaded for us.
git checkout Ubuntu-4.15.0-20.21
fakeroot debian/rules clean
debian/rules updateconfigs
fakeroot debian/rules build-generic
linux_image="$(pwd)/debian/build/build-generic/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage"
```

This produced the exact same config and I believe used the exact same source code as the packaged Ubuntu that `debootstrap` downloaded as explained at: [Where can I get the 11.04 kernel .config file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28047/where-can-i-get-the-11-04-kernel-config-file/1081647#1081647)

Then I patched it with:

```
diff --git a/init/main.c b/init/main.c
index b8b121c17ff1..542229349efc 100644
--- a/init/main.c
+++ b/init/main.c
@@ -516,6 +516,8 @@ asmlinkage __visible void __init start_kernel(void)
        char *command_line;
        char *after_dashes;

+ pr_info("I'VE HACKED THE LINUX KERNEL!!!");
+
        set_task_stack_end_magic(&init_task);
        smp_setup_processor_id();
        debug_objects_early_init();
```

and rebuild:

```
fakeroot debian/rules build-generic
```

and it did print my message during boot:

```
I'VE HACKED THE LINUX KERNEL!!!
```

The rebuild was not very fast though, so maybe there is a better command? I just waited for it to say:

```
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#3)
```

and went ahead with the run.

### debootstrap arm64

The procedure was similar to the amd64 one, but with the following differences:

1)

We must do a two stage `debootstrap`:

- first with `--foreign` to just download the packages
- then we install QEMU static into the `chroot`
- then we do the package installation with `--second-stage` using QEMU user mode emulation + [`binfmt_misc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt/40938801#40938801)

See also: [What is debootstrap --second-stage for](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287789/what-is-debootstrap-second-stage-for/1082115#1082115)

2. the default kernel boot fails at the end with:

   [    0.773665] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
   [    0.774033] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

The empty partition list indicates that there is a serious error with the disk driver, after a bit of trying the missing option is:

```
CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK=y
```

I think it works when I use the ISO because the modules must get loaded from the initrd.

I tried to use other disk types, but virtio is the only valid value for `-drive if=` when `-M virt`, which is the saner machine type nowadays.

Therefore we must recompile our own kernel with that option enabled, as explained here: [When cross-compiling the kernel, how can I stop it making from clean every time when I just want to modify one file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802701/kernel-build-cross-compile/802752#802752)

Ubuntu devs should turn this CONFIG `y` by default! It is very useful!

TODO: the network is not working, the error message is:

```
root@ciro-p51:~# systemctl status dhclient.service
root@ciro-p51:~# cat f
● dhclient.service - DHCP Client
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dhclient.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Sun 2018-01-28 15:58:42 UTC; 2min 2s ago
     Docs: man:dhclient(8)
  Process: 171 ExecStart=/sbin/dhclient -4 -q (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 28 15:58:40 ciro-p51 systemd[1]: Starting DHCP Client...
Jan 28 15:58:42 ciro-p51 dhclient[171]: No broadcast interfaces found - exiting.
Jan 28 15:58:42 ciro-p51 systemd[1]: dhclient.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/dhclient.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Jan 28 15:58:42 ciro-p51 systemd[1]: dhclient.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Jan 28 15:58:42 ciro-p51 systemd[1]: Failed to start DHCP Client.
```

Here is the fully automated script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# https://askubuntu.com/questions/281763/is-there-any-prebuilt-qemu-ubuntu-image32bit-online/1081171#1081171

set -eux

debootstrap_dir=debootstrap
root_filesystem=debootstrap.ext2.qcow2

sudo apt-get install \
  gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu \
  debootstrap \
  libguestfs-tools \
  qemu-system-aarch64 \
  qemu-user-static \
;

if [ ! -d "$debootstrap_dir" ]; then
  sudo debootstrap \
    --arch arm64 \
    --foreign \
    bionic \
    "$debootstrap_dir" \
    http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports \
  ;
  sudo mkdir -p "${debootstrap_dir}/usr/bin"
  sudo cp "$(which qemu-aarch64-static)" "${debootstrap_dir}/usr/bin"
  sudo chroot "$debootstrap_dir" /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
  sudo rm -f "$root_filesystem"
fi

linux_image="$(printf "${debootstrap_dir}/boot/vmlinuz-"*)"

if [ ! -f "$root_filesystem" ]; then
  # Set root password.
  echo 'root:root' | sudo chroot "$debootstrap_dir" chpasswd

  # Remount root filesystem as rw.
  cat << EOF | sudo tee "${debootstrap_dir}/etc/fstab"
/dev/sda / ext4 errors=remount-ro,acl 0 1
EOF

  # Automaticaly start networking.
  # Otherwise network commands fail with:
  #     Temporary failure in name resolution
  # https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045278/ubuntu-server-18-04-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution/1080902#1080902
  cat << EOF | sudo tee "${debootstrap_dir}/etc/systemd/system/dhclient.service"
[Unit]
Description=DHCP Client
Documentation=man:dhclient(8)
Wants=network.target
Before=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/dhclient.pid
ExecStart=/sbin/dhclient -4 -q

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
  sudo ln -sf "${debootstrap_dir}/etc/systemd/system/dhclient.service" \
    "${debootstrap_dir}/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhclient.service"

  # Why Ubuntu, why.
  # https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/759725
  sudo chmod +r "${linux_image}"

  # Generate image file from debootstrap directory.
  # Leave 1Gb extra empty space in the image.
  sudo virt-make-fs \
    --format qcow2 \
    --size +1G \
    --type ext2 \
    "$debootstrap_dir" \
    "$root_filesystem" \
  ;
  sudo chmod 666 "$root_filesystem"
fi

# Build the Linux kernel.
linux_image="$(pwd)/linux/debian/build/build-generic/arch/arm64/boot/Image"
if [ ! -f "$linux_image" ]; then
  git clone --branch Ubuntu-4.15.0-20.21 --depth 1 git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git linux
  cd linux
patch -p1 << EOF
diff --git a/debian.master/config/config.common.ubuntu b/debian.master/config/config.common.ubuntu
index 5ff32cb997e9..8a190d3a0299 100644
--- a/debian.master/config/config.common.ubuntu
+++ b/debian.master/config/config.common.ubuntu
@@ -10153,7 +10153,7 @@ CONFIG_VIDEO_ZORAN_ZR36060=m
 CONFIG_VIPERBOARD_ADC=m
 CONFIG_VIRTIO=y
 CONFIG_VIRTIO_BALLOON=y
-CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK=m
+CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK=y
 CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK_SCSI=y
 CONFIG_VIRTIO_CONSOLE=y
 CONFIG_VIRTIO_INPUT=m
EOF
  export ARCH=arm64
  export $(dpkg-architecture -aarm64)
  export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
  fakeroot debian/rules clean
  debian/rules updateconfigs
  fakeroot debian/rules DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=parallel=`nproc` build-generic
  cd -
fi

qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -append 'console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/vda rootfstype=ext2' \
  -device rtl8139,netdev=net0 \
  -drive "file=${root_filesystem},format=qcow2" \
  -kernel "${linux_image}" \
  -m 2G \
  -netdev user,id=net0 \
  -serial mon:stdio \
  -M virt,highmem=off \
  -cpu cortex-a57 \
  -nographic \
;
```

[GitHub Upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/blob/01975ed828f28e82750615460e7be11dc91c9e8b/debootstrap-ubuntu-qemu-arm.sh).

### Desktop image

See: [How to run Ubuntu desktop on QEMU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884534/how-to-run-ubuntu-16-04-desktop-on-qemu/1046792#1046792)

It does require going through the installer manually, but it is the most stable thing you can possibly do, and totally fine if you just want to get a VM for interactive use running from time to time.

For aarch64, I haven't gotten the desktop working yet maybe keep an eye out for: [How to run Ubuntu 16.04 ARM in QEMU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797599/how-to-run-ubuntu-16-04-arm-in-qemu)

### Debian aarch64

https://gist.github.com/philipz/04a9a165f8ce561f7ddd and change `sudo mount /dev/nbd0p2` to `nbd0p1`.

Comment: I modified your script a little bit: https://gist.github.com/lnyng/8342947a1d5455303fd8730c9ca35da0
The main change is to create a dhclient systemd unit to avoid installing network-manager, which requires many UI related libraries (about 300+MB for my installation).

Comment: @lyang thanks! You've allowed me to not learn systemd properly once more :-)

Comment: @lyang when I tried it for arm64 as explained in the updated answer, I get the error: `dhclient.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/dhclient.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory`, any clues? After boot I am able to `touch /var/run/a`.

Comment: Seems to be a permission error. Maybe changing the pid path to other places like /tmp/dhclient.pid? Or just remove it altogether if we don't really care to kill that process...

Comment: Thanks! This answer really helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/ which contains cloud images which can be used with qemu/kvm.

Comment: How do you use those images, then? More precisely: How do you log in?

Comment: you can add your ssh keys through cloud-init

Comment: @FrederickNord To login https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137679/login-credentials-of-ubuntu-cloud-server-image/54440564#54440564

Answer (score 0):

https://www.turnkeylinux.org/ has been around for ages. They have a huge catalog downloadable, premade "appliance" like images in numerous formats (ova, iso, vdmk, openstack, xen). They even can launch an image right in AWS for you.

When I want to start exploring a particular stack or need to knock out a problem, I frequently will download on of their images, convert it to a cow2 and use it.

You can also grab images from https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search or https://virtualboxes.org/images/ and convert them as well.