# apt update fails within proot

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, chroot, debootstrap

I'm building an image for an arm64 machine in a docker environment. I get the 20.04 base system by starting with

```
debootstrap --components=main --arch=arm64 --foreign focal ./mnt http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
```

and then finish the install by entering the `proot` and issuing

```
debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
```

After that I can adapt a few more things and then successfully deploy the image. I can even install additional packages which are already on the index. The only thing that does not work is to do

```
apt update
```

within the `proot`. That fails with the following error message:

```
root@502827f30e52:/# apt update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
  Couldn't execute /usr/bin/apt-key to check /var/lib/apt/lists/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_focal_InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease: Couldn't execute /usr/bin/apt-key to check /var/lib/apt/lists/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_focal_InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/InRelease  Couldn't execute /usr/bin/apt-key to check /var/lib/apt/lists/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_focal_InRelease
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I checked if `/usr/bin/apt-key` is there and indeed, it is right where it should be and seems to be running OK. When I want to do something like `apt-key list` it asks me to install one of the additional packages `gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1`. If I do that it seems to run fine, so I guess this is normal behavior?

Any ideas on how I could track down why `apt update`/`apt-key` is failing?

Comment: Try this, exact problem and in docker too --> https://superuser.com/a/1545323/1106777.

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/1082115/66509 .