# When cross-compiling the kernel, how can I stop it making from clean every time when I just want to modify one file?

Tags: kernel, cross-compilation

I'm doing a cross-compile Ubuntu kernel build.

I am following instructions for building Ubuntu for omap:

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
do_tools=false skipabi=true skipmodule=true dpkg-buildpackage -B -aarmhf -uc -us
```

But the above always makes it from clean, and takes a lot of time.
I just make a change in the same file, so I don't need to rebuild from clean.

I have tried to skip the line `fakeroot debian/rules clean`
and also removed `-uc`, but it still does it from clean.

I then tried another method and did:

```
make -j3 deb-pkg
```

But then I got a new error:

```
dpkg-deb: building package `linux-firmware-image' in `../linux-firmware-image_3.4.27+-1_all.deb'.
dpkg-gencontrol: error: current host architecture 'armhf' does not appear in package's architecture list ()
make[1]: *** [deb-pkg] Error 255
```

Then I needed to wait ~2 hours for build to finish...

All I'm trying to do is to modify a board file (unfortunately I can't make it a module, as far as I understand).

Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Ubuntu debian packaged kernels, I build arm64 kernels much like the following (you should be able to substitute arm64 for the armhf arch specific flags that match your target and cross-compiler).

```
export ARCH=arm64
export $(dpkg-architecture -aarm64); export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-

fakeroot debian/rules clean
debian/rules build
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

For subsequent builds, I use:

```
rm debian/stamps/stamp-build*
debian/rules build
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

Comment: Hi, I get an error .....  install -m755 debian/tools/generic /home/user/kernel/kernel-ubuntu/debian/linux-ti-omap4-tools-common/usr/sbin/hv_kvp_daemon; \
 fi
install: cannot stat `debian/tools/generic': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-tools] Error 1

Comment: Worth mentioning that most users will want to build just one kernel with `build-generic` and `binary-generic`, otherwise e.g. `Ubuntu-4.15.0-20.21` builds two: one for `debian.master/config/arm64/config.flavour.generic` and one for `config.flavour.snapdragon`.